# Calling multiple clients from API controller methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Hi   I have a requirement where in I have to call two different client methods from same api in .NET Core and I have structured my code as follows. THis is working fine but Please give me your valuable inputs or suggestions for improvements.

I am using HTTPClientFactory to create my clients as shown below:

```
  public class CustomerApiClient : ICustomerApiClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClientCustomer;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClientProduct;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public CustomerApiClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<CustomerApiClient> logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
            this._httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            this._configuration = configuration;

            _httpClientCustomer = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("CustomerService");
            var authApiKey = configuration.GetSection("CustomerAuthApiKey")?.Value;
            _httpClientCustomer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AuthApiKey", authApiKey);

            _httpClientProduct = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ProductService");
            var authApiKeyImageManagementService = configuration.GetSection("ProductAuthApiKey")?.Value;
            _httpClientProduct.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AuthApiKey", authApiKeyImageManagementService);


        }


        public virtual async Task<object> GetCustomerDetailsAsync(int customerId)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("customerId");

            var uri = string.Concat(_httpClientCustomer?.BaseAddress, $"/GetCustomerBycustomerId?customer={customerId}");
            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
            {
                using (var response = await _httpClientCustomer.SendAsync(requestMessage, CancellationToken.None))
                {
                    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                    var strStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        if (strStream.ToLower() == "null")
                        {
                            return null;
                        }

                        JObject respJobject = JObject.Parse(strStream);
                        var resultCustomer = respJobject;

                    }
                }
            }

            // the resultCustomer object wil have productId in it. Will be using the productId for below  service -- /product/productId . Have not written the code for it so hardcoded it as 1102

            var uriProductService = string.Concat(_httpClientProduct?.BaseAddress, $"/product/1102");

            using (var requestMessage1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uriProductService))
            {
                using (var response = await _httpClientProduct.SendAsync(requestMessage1, CancellationToken.None))
                {
                    var stream1 = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                    var strStream1 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                       return ApiHelper.DeserializeJson<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Product>>(stream1);
                    }

                    var content = await ApiHelper.StreamToStringAsync(stream1);
                    throw new ApiException
                    {
                        StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
                        Content = content
                    };
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

My Startup.cs file contains the following in ConfigureDependencies method

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("CustomerService", im =>
            {
                im.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://Testserver-Phse2.net/Shared/CustomerService/api/v1/Customers");
            });

            serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("ProductService", dc =>
            {
                dc.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("ApiUrls:ProductServiceApi")?.Value); 
            });

            serviceCollection.AddScoped<ICustomerApiClient, CustomerApiClient>();
```

**And if you observe this  line    `JObject respJobject = JObject.Parse(strStream);`
I am converting my stream to JObject and then using linq to loop through it. Is it a good thing or should I create a localized DTO Customer object and deserialize into it like shown below.. Which approach is better in terms of optimization**

```
 var objectResponse_ = ApiHelper.DeserializeJson<Customer>(stream)
```

ApiHelper.cs

```
public static class APiHelper
   
              public static T DeserializeJsonFromStream<T>(Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream == null || !stream.CanRead)
                return default(T);

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var js = new JsonSerializer();
                js.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
                var searchResult = js.Deserialize<T>(jtr);
                return searchResult;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you fix the typos in the code first?

Comment: I have done them. Sorry for it.

Comment: Still typos there. Doesn't compile.

Comment: not sure why . dont see any more typos.

Comment: Insert the code into IDE, it will highlight the typos.

Comment: thank you for the tip. please check now

Comment: `GetCustomerDetailsAsync` still doesn't compile as it must return a value of type `object`. Note the this site allows for review only the fully working as intended code. Pseudo code, theoretical code, obfuscated code, or not working as intended code isn't suitable for review. Please fix the code build successfully. Also include all custom interfaces as well as other base implementaions if it needed to support the reviewing code. What is `ApiHelper`?

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with me aepot. I am a newbie to this forum so kindly excuse my errors. I have updated my question.

Comment: Any feedback on my question that is in bold letters above?

Answer (score 1):

**Magic Strings** 
Fix the magic strings issue and use constants instead for your string inputs - it'll make code changes far easier to do

**Unclear intention based on naming** 
`_logger.LogDebug("customerId");` are you intending to output the `customerId` passed into the method there? Its not clear.

**Unnecessary URI declaration** 
`var uri = string.Concat(_httpClientCustomer?.BaseAddress, $"/GetCustomerBycustomerId?customer={customerId}");` That base address can be setup when you create the HTTP Client. So the only URL you need to pass into the call to: `using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))` is the end part of the URI

**Reading the Response Stream Multiple Times** 
You are reading the stream twice, but only using one of them?

```
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

var strStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Null Check Required Values** 
Do you need null checks for these values and only add the header if the value exists?

```
_httpClientCustomer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AuthApiKey", authApiKey);
```